# Razor Pages html tag error. BR tag is OK but table tag raises a build error

Tags: razor-pages

I get errors in Razor pages depending on the HTML tag type.

`<BR>` is ok, but `</table>` produces a large number of errors and cannot be built.

I don't know why, as I think the syntax is correct for Razor Pages. Please let me know!

This code is OK.

```
@foreach (StaffShiftModel.ShiftRecord r in Model.ShiftRecords)
{
    int curWeekNum = r.WeekNum;

    if (curWeekNum != lastWeekNum && lastWeekNum != 0)
    {
        <BR>
    }
}
```

This code produces a large number of errors. I just changed 
 to .

```
@foreach (StaffShiftModel.ShiftRecord r in Model.ShiftRecords)
{
    int curWeekNum = r.WeekNum;

    if (curWeekNum != lastWeekNum && lastWeekNum != 0)
    {
        <table>
    }
}
```

`<table></table>`
is OK.

`@:</table>`
is also OK.

Comment: Can you please clarify why you expect `<table>` to produce some sensible result? How do you expect it to figure out where it must be closed? C#/Razor pages are very different from HTML in accepting complete garbage markup - HTML would try to do something, C#/Razor will error out. (Or maybe your question is "why BR is self-closing tag as defined in HTML standards"?)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It was a very simple reason. The reason was simple, but my understanding was better.

Answer (score 0):

Razor expects HTML tags to be balanced:

> All elements must be either self-closing or have a matching end tag

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-7.0#razor-syntax

Comment: Thank you! It was a simple thing, but has increased my very understanding.